# What were existing files from working-tree at a given commit?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-worktree

I want to know, if it's possible, what were the existing files from my working-tree at the time that a concrete commit was made.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git ls-tree -r --name-only <commit>`.

`-r` recurses into subdirectories, `--name-only` prevents display of git metadata.

Comment: Thank you Amadan !  This is almost what I need.  Output only lacks **untracked files**.

Comment: Given that untracked files are untracked, it is not possible to know which files existed at the time the commit was made.

Comment: Exactly. You are right. There is no way. Thanks again !

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you shouldn't take it personally. A Stack Overflow downvote is not about you — the community is very Q&A centered, SO is primarily a repository of Q&A, and a downvote simply means they don't think the question or the answer would be useful to many people in the future (even if the question is great, but only of use in a very specific situation that is unlikely to happen again, a downvote is warranted). If a question is outright bad, you wouldn't be getting (only) downvotes, but close votes, or even flags.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Amadan.  ;-)

Comment: @Xcode_Manolo Another clarification: your duty, when you receive an answer that solves the problem, is to _accept_ that answer (checkmark to its left). Acceptance is the coin of the realm at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thxs Matt ! Amadan’s answer accepted ! Yesterday i couldn’t for some reason relative to my noob state (<15 points)